# Creating # pages like Twitter with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I have a question to the Firebase community.

How to structure the data for # pages like Twitter? (e.g:#funnyVideos so that any one can see that link and add some stuff into it) in Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to store hash tags.

But that enough is not enough to determine your data model.

In Firebase (as in most NoSQL databases) you model your data for the way you app consumes it. So you'll have to determine what screens there are in your app and what information they show.

For example, if you want to show the hash tags per page, you'd store a list of hash tags per page:

```
hashtagsPerPage
    pageId1
        hashTag1: true
        hashTag2: true
    pageId2
        hashTag1: true
        hashTag3: true
```

If you also want a list of pages for a given hash tag, you'd **also** store:

```
pagesPerHashtag
    hashTag1
        pageId1: true
        pageId2: true
    hashTag2
        pageId1: true
    hashTag3
        pageId2: true
```

And of course you'd then have the list of pages itself:

```
pages
    pageId1
        title: "Creating # pages like Twitter with Firebase"
        url: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947270/creating-pages-like-twitter-with-firebase"
    pageId2
        title: "Structure Your Database"
        url: "https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data"
```

I highly recommend that you read both the [Firebase documentation on data structuring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout) (the first two lists are the structure documented in the section "create data that scales").

In addition there's this great primer on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: there are two buttons in app..one button to create pages in app. For example user1 Created a page named "Funnyjokes". And user2 clicks on "create new post button" and added a image with "#Funnyjokes" hashtag from his app screen.....then "funnyjokes" page have to show user2 added image...kindly help me